# Which Source Code Management System Suits My Needs Best? Git or SVN? How do you diff excel spreadsheets?

Tags: svn, git, macos, excel, vba

I am currently looking at the efficiency and ease of our companies source code / resource management tools..

For the last couple of months i have been using Git to manage all of my web development code and images.. and for me it works fine.

However some of my colleges aren't entirely comfortable using the command line.

our company works with both mac's and PC's and we heavily work with visual studio and MS VBA. we also work quite a lot with Photoshop CS4

I have been considering moving our company onto subversion.

My Reasoning is:

- There's some great mac gui clients (i.e. Versions)
- Theres a great Photoshop Plugin (Pixelnovel)
- we work fairly centeralised

My Questions are:

- Which SCM would suit our needs best?
- Are there any tools available to Diff the VBA code in excel macros
- Are there any SVN Clients As Slick as Versions available for windows?

Thanks a Lot

Daniel

Comment: It might be worth noting that Office files use zip compression (starting with 2007). Are you using a version of Excel recent enough to take advantage of this, or is your version older?

Comment: we use 2007, 2010 and 2003.. but have found 2003 to be REALLY unstable.. the boss was almost in tears when his excel spreadsheet corrupted and wiped 5 hours of hardcore datachewing VBA, so where does the zip thing leave us on diffing the modules? is it possible if so what would i use?

Answer (score 3):

I think Subversion would be very well suited.  There's a good windows client, [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) which is very simple, the server is simple to set up on Windows, Mac or Linux, and it fits with your centralised model.  I wouldn't suggest using git as the client GUIs aren't as mature and it's a lot more complex model to get your head around for less technical users.

Comment: +1 for mentioning TortoiseSVN. It's really easy to use and it's free.

Comment: And also GitX is very good for Mac. Gitk, git citool, git gui are available on all platforms. Those are enough for 99.9% of tasks you'll ever need with Git.

Comment: My point was more that I think for less technical users, SVN is simpler to get into than git.  I've recently had a huge amount of headaches trying to get a git server up and running and dealing with linefeed issues, whereas SVN is easier to get running out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, it depends on what you want to do.

One way to look at it:
If you want to check in larger binaries, I have found that svn works better.  IF you want to merge text files, git is better.

If you have the money @ericgorr is right, Perforce is much nicer to work with then svn.

Comment: Don't really have the $700 for each user! i think svn is starting to look more and more attractive!

Answer (score 1):

If you can afford it, I would suggest [Perforce](http://perforce.com). The P4V GUI client is excellent. They support Mac, Windows, LINUX, & Unix

Answer (score 1):

You can make Git work to how you like. See why people are having issues and address them. Ease of use means putting a ceiling on productivity. Git's the most powerful thing out there for VCS.

Careful if you plan on merging work if you're not using Git...

Comment: He would be merging binary files. Git doesn't help with that (nothing does).